# Getting unique items from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a question about Objective-C today involving NSMutableArray. Coming from a .net/c# background I'm having some trouble working with these things.

Let's say I have an object called "Song"

My song has 3 properties:

- Title
- Artist
- Genre

I have a NSMutableArray or NSArray which holds all my Song objects.

How would I go about trying to 'query' my array to get a new array with only (Unique) Artists or Genre's.

Where as in .net you would write a simple LINQ query with a DISTINCT clause, how would one solve this in Objective-C? I'm guessing with predicates but am struggling to find a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "unique artists," there are a couple of different solutions. If you just want to get all the artists and don't want any to appear more than once, just do `[NSSet setWithArray:[songArray valueForKey:@"artist"]]`. If you mean you want to set a list of all the songs which are the only song by their artist, you need to first find the artists who only do one song and then find the songs by those artists:

```
NSCountedSet *artistsWithCounts = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:[songArray valueForKey:@"artist"]];
NSMutableSet *uniqueArtists = [NSMutableSet set];
for (id artist in artistsWithCounts)
    if ([artistsWithCounts countForObject:artist] == 1])
        [uniqueArtists addObject:artist];
NSPredicate *findUniqueArtists = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"artist IN %@", uniqueArtists];
NSArray *songsWithUniqueArtists = [songArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:findUniqueArtists];
```

Comment: So let say we have in the array  - among the others - two songs of one artist. Then, according to @"artist IN %@" predicate all two appear in songsWithUniqueArtists array. I prefer to use NSMutableDictionary, and add objects with unique keys.

Answer (score 37):

You could also use:

```
NSArray *uniqueArtists = [songs valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.artist"];
NSArray *uniqueGenres = [songs valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.genre"];
```

Likewise, if you need to compare the entire object you could create a new readonly property that combines the values you want to match on (via a hash or otherwise) dynamically and compare on that:

```
NSArray *array = [songs valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.hash"];
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind this returns the uniques values for the specified property, not the objects themselves. So it will be an array of NSString values, not Song values.

Comment: Very nice; be aware of the caveat the valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.the_property" does not preserve sort order.

Comment: Any way to get the Song value instead of the string

Comment: If you want the distinct objects you should use a set as in the accepted answer. You can convert the array to a set using the -setWithArray initializer (or better, start with a set from the start if possible). You can also use -isEqual and -hash to override the default mechanism for determining uniqueness of the object.

Answer (score 5):

Or like this:

```objectivec
filterTags  = [[NSSet setWithArray:filterTags] allObjects];
```

`filterTags` was not unique at first, but becomes unique after the operation.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be directly applicable but it is a solution to creating a unique set of values...
Assume you have a NSMutable array of events that have multiple duplicate entries.  This array is named eventArray.  The NSSet object can be used to trim that array and then repopulate that array as shown below...

```
NSSet *uniqueEvents = [NSSet setWithArray:eventArray];

[eventArray removeAllObjects];

[eventArray addObjectsFromArray:[uniqueEvents allObjects]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use NSOrderedSet instead of NSSet.

```
NSOrderedSet *uniqueOrderedSet = [NSOrderedSet setWithArray:itemsArray];
[itemsArray removeAllObjects];
[itemsArray addObjectsFromArray:[uniqueOrderedSet allObjects]];
```

Answer (score -2):

I've created a simple query API for Objective-C that makes this kind of task a lot easier. Using the [Linq-to-ObjectiveC distinct](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC#distinct) method, retrieving songs with unique artists would involve the following:

```
NSArray* songsWithUniqueArtistists = [input distinct:^id(id song) {
    return [song artist];
}];
```

This returns a list of song instances, each with a unique artist.